# Sort list by content type

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, content-type

We have a list grouped by content type:



Now we want to sort our groups by the order of our list content types. Is this possible? 
The possibility of sort from a-z would also be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that you can group by content type via SharePoint Designer by substituting the name of an existing grouping field in a programmatic fashion ([More information may be found on this site](http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2010/06/how-to-group-by-content-type-in-sharepoint-2010/)).

I am less clear as to whether doing this makes the new 'content type' field reusable for sorting purposes.

Another means of going about actual sorting [is mentioned on this second website.](http://www.go4sharepoint.com/Forum/content-types-grouping-24154.aspx)

Basically this involves either:

- Turning on metadata navigation in the library, or
- Using search refinement